# Anonymous type error when using JOIN in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm getting an error when using a join in a LINQ statement:

'HalftimeHomeGoals is not a member of anonymous type; it does not exist in the current context'.

```
         Dim HomeAllLP = (From a In db.Matches
                         Join b In db.MatchesLeagues On a.Id Equals b.Id
                         Where (a.HomeTeam = HomeTeam)
                         Order By a.Date Descending
                         Select a, b)



        For Each y In HomeAllLP
            If (y.HalfTimeHomeGoals > 0) Or (y.HalfTimeAwayGoals > 0) Then
                HFHGL2 = HFHGL2 + 1
            End If
        Next
```

It works fine if I only select a, but if I try and select my joined table as well it gives the error, so I can't access my joined table.

I have looked this up but don't understand any of the answers I've found so far and they are all in C#, I'm using VB.NET.

Comment: How about `y.a.HalfTimeHomeGoals`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to `select` both types, it is nevertheless a new type. you can select them in an object of anonymous type like

```
Dim HomeAllLP = (From a In db.Matches
                         Join b In db.MatchesLeagues On a.Id Equals b.Id
                         Where (a.HomeTeam = HomeTeam)
                         Order By a.Date Descending
                         Select New With {a, b})
```

Then in foreach you can acess properties of a or b like

```
For Each y In HomeAllLP
            If (y.a.HalfTimeHomeGoals > 0) Or (y.b.HalfTimeAwayGoals > 0) Then
                HFHGL2 = HFHGL2 + 1
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that both classes Matches and MatchesLeagues contain a field/property named HalfTimeHomeGoals the following code should work:

```
For Each y In HomeAllLP
    If (y.a.HalfTimeHomeGoals > 0) Or (y.b.HalfTimeHomeGoals > 0) Then
       HFHGL2 = HFHGL2 + 1
    End If
Next
```